# How to access internal json object in Spring Rest Request

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I want to create one API which format will be like below.

```
{
           "jsonObject": {
                     //some json object     
           },
           "key": "SampleKey",
           "jsonDataKey": "SampleDataKey"
}
```

for this I have created the RequestBody class as below.

```
public class ParentJsonInfo {
public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

private String key;

public JsonObject getJsonData() {
    return jsonData;
}

public void setJsonData(JsonObject jsonData) {
    this.jsonData = jsonData;
}

private JsonObject jsonData;

public String getJsonDataKey() {
    return jsonDataKey;
}

public void setJsonDataKey(String jsonDataKey) {
    this.jsonDataKey = jsonDataKey;
}

private String jsonDataKey;
```

}

but unfortunately I am not getting any data inside the json object of my class. M I doing anything wrong. please guide me to how should i access the data inside that object.

Here is the controller method code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postNews", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Greeting greeting(@RequestBody ParentJsonInfo parentJsonInfo) {
 Jsonobject jsonObject= parentJsonInfo.getjsonObject();
}
```

Comment: show more code. The controller especially, so we can help you out with your issue.

Comment: added the controller method as well

Comment: The key used in json string is jsonObject, but you declared it as jsonData in your model. Rename it to jsonObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are trying to deserialize `jsonObject` which is from your json, but your field is called `jsonData`.
As @Mushtu mentioned, you need to rename that field.

Here is your ParentJsonInfo with a few adjustments:

- moving the fields to the top (it is a good practice to group fields and methods separately)
- renamed your field from `jsonData` to `jsonObject`

ParentJsonInfo:

```
public class ParentJsonInfo {

    private String key;
    private JsonObject jsonObject;
    private String jsonDataKey;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public JsonObject getJsonObject() {
        return jsonObject;
    }

    public void setJsonObject(JsonObject jsonObject) {
        this.jsonObject = jsonObject;
    }

    public String getJsonDataKey() {
        return jsonDataKey;
    }

    public void setJsonDataKey(String jsonDataKey) {
        this.jsonDataKey = jsonDataKey;
    }
}
```

JsonObject:

```
public class JsonObject {

    private Map<String, Object> other = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        return other;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String name, String value) {
        other.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this change but still it is not working.. the json object is coming as empty

Comment: @AndroidDev
`"jsonObject": {
                     //some json object     
           },`. We need more info then :) both the json and the pojo in order to help you

Comment: Some json object means you can consider here any json object with any properties

Comment: @AndroidDev I've updated my answer with a possible solution to get the data from the json. I am not entirely sure what `JsonObject` is though. Is it your own object or is it something from a library?

Answer (score 0):

u can modify like this

```
public Greeting greeting(@RequestBody String parentJsonInfo) {
 // parse string to jsonobject
}
```